# How to perform a sophisticated "if statement" using re.findall/search within HTML code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am accessing a website extracting the title and trying to examine whether this matches something I've extracted elsewhere. I'm setting some arbitrary parameters but some assistance would be great!

So I have Multiple Strings Generated From Webscraping:

```
A = LondonHospital
B = LondonHospitalOne
C = LondonHospitalTwo
```

I want to match one of these best suited to another string I have collated elsewhere, let's call this X:

```
X = LoundonHospiTaL
```

I want to find a way to match this expression best to A, I'm not sure what sort of parameters to include, I thought having a statement like so long as 80% of the characters exist (in whatever order), such as Y (shown below), this would compensate for typo errors? I'd rather this match with A, those B or C? I know this sounds like a rather loose question, but some advice would be much appreciated! Oh, and the end result would be to extract A alone.

```
Y = oLnudnoohspitla
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want is *fuzzy string matching*. RegEx won’t be of any help there. Maybe look into [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/).

Comment: Read about the Levenshtein Edit Distance algorithm. There is a Python inplementation: fuzzywuzzy.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks guys. have not explored this.